# Best way to exchange datetime values between client and server

Tags: javascript, python, timezone

Can anybody plz answer these?

1. what could the best date-time format that can be used to exchange date-time values from client to server and vice-versa since we have many options like offset, TZ timezone name(Asia/Kolkata, America/New_York, ..), standard timezone names(CDT,IST,..) etc?
2. Which is the recommended JavaScript library file (for client side) and python library (for server side) that makes timezone conversions easier?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question shows no research effort.  These are easy to find with a bit of searching.  Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.  Try Google.

Comment: I don't need your useless suggestion but answers. Do you think people don't know googling? If people use google, why stackoverflow is for?

Comment: Stack Overflow has guidelines.  Your question does not follow them.  You can read more in:  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should use UTC datetimes to that you have a unique standard reference to work with datetimes
2. on Python, use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) ; for javascript you may have a look at [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)